# Android Loading a fragment when the app is started

Tags: java, android, fragment, runnable, navigation-drawer

I am trying to have a navigation drawer that let me choose different kinds of fragment.
I implemented a Runnable() thread so the transition is a bit more smooth when the fragment changes.
However after I implemented that, it does not load a default fragment on the start, meaning it will appear blank and I have to click into the navigation drawer to display something on the srart.

I want it to be able to display the first item on the menu at the start of the app (menu 0 )

Here is some code snippet

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(final int position) {
     mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
                changeFragment(position);
            }
        };

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPAGETitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

private void changeFragment(final int position)
{
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment(MainActivity.this);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,     
 fragment).commit();
    fragmentChanged =true;
}

public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        //     
 onPrepareOptionsMenu()

            if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
                mPendingRunnable = null;
            }
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                    "Downloading Data",
                    "Please wait while Data are downloaded");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.isIndeterminate();
            progress.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load your first fragment in the onCreate method of your activity. When the user selects an option from the naviagtion drawer menu, you replace the already existing fragment layout with a new one.

Comment: Hey Anirudh,  I understand that but my problem is it crashes when I try to do that.

Comment: Found the bug, progress dialog was not initialized, my bad boys